# Make a pointer on an object that has a reference member?

Tags: c++, pointers

I'm a student beginner in C++ (but yet have few hours on C), and I'm actually having a problem to use a pointer on my object. I really tried to find infos on the web, but it was pointless (pointless-pointer, do you get it ?!). So I try my luck here.

This code compiles now ! My apologies to all of you that try the code before that. Compiled with :

`g++ -Wall -o exec main.cc`

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <vector>

 //all the includes here
 using namespace std;

 class ExpLog
 {
 public: 
   virtual string toString() const=0;
   //virtual int evaluate() const=0;
 };


 class Atom : public ExpLog
 {    
 protected:
   int value;

 public:
   Atom():value(0){}
   string toString() const
   {
     return "a";//definition doesn't matter here
   } 

 };


 class ExpNot : public ExpLog
 {    
 protected:
   const ExpLog& opd; 

 public:
   ExpNot(const Atom& a):opd(a){}
   string toString() const
   {
     return "NOT"+opd.toString();
   }

 };

 const ExpLog *my_function(vector<Atom> const& vect_atom, int i)
 {
   if(i>= vect_atom.size()) return NULL;

   const Atom *a =  &vect_atom[i]       ;

   if(i>0) 
     return a;
   else{
     ExpNot *n;
     n = new ExpNot(*a);
     cout<<n->toString()<<endl; //This line leads to a seg:fault
     return n;         

   }
 }


 int main()
 {
   int i=-2;
   vector<Atom> vect_atom(3);

   my_function(vect_atom, i);
 }
```

Comment: `const ExpLog&;` doesn't compile.

Comment: you must have warnings also as you seem to do spurious const_cast

Comment: How can you possible instantiate `ExpNot`? It's an abstract class, just like `Atom` and `ExpLog`.

Comment: arf my bad, I tried to make a simple version of my code, to be more specific to my problem. I corrected it and added my main,  it should help

Comment: @R.DJC It still doesn't compile (even after I added `#include <string>`): https://ideone.com/n2MOfl Please fix your code so that it compiles without any modifications whatsoever. Please also try my answer and see if that is the cause.

Comment: Ok, sorry, my attempt to make it more simple finally failed. I'm currently trying to fix it

Comment: "Code doesn't work" is not a valid problem description per asking guidelines. Please provide a [mcve] and don't forget to include expected results.

Comment: You're absolutly right. Really sorry about that, I was not expecting that were a tons of mistake. I'm fixing this right now

Comment: So you are passing `-2` to `my_function`. What do you expect `&vect_atom[-2]` to be?

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, this code snippet(s) does not compile in its current form. However, I'm willing to guess the problem is not in the line you have indicated, but the line

```
const Atom *a =  &vect_atom[i]
```

If `i > vect_atom.size()` then this will point outside of the vector. Try adding a check for this just like you have a check for `i < 0`. If that check does match, then search up the for the root cause: the caller that is passing an invalid index.

Comment: This code compile actually. This code is a simplified version (to avoid useless details), so i forget this step, but you're right about the vector.size()

Comment: I believe you that your original code compiles. But if the snippet you post in your question doesn't, then it is impossible for us to help you properly. (We can guess, like I just did, but this is usually a waste of time.)